# In the orignal series does Hinata die?

Tags: naruto

I just finished episode 46 (or 47) of the original series. Towards the end of the episode it shows Hinata being taken away, but it is never made clear whether she is dead or alive definitively. Naruto dips his fingers in her blood she coughed up, and says something about never losing. At first I thought that meant he was going to avenge her in some sort of way (implying death), but I'm not entirely sure.

This is sort of a two part question:

- Is Hinata alive?
- Will she show up again in the original series, or does she end up coming back in Shippuden?

Keep in mind I've not watched past episode 51-ish, and I'm watching the original series.

Comment: just a hint, i haven't seen Hinata die but if she does actually die and not just badly wounded and knocked out, Naruto will go more ballistic than he did when he though Haku killed Sasuke at the start of the series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She is alive, she is around in Shippuden as she is just as shy around Naruto during the moment Naruto is seeing everyone together for the first time in years.

she does show up again multiple times during the fillers of the original series, especially when she unveils her own 8 Tri-gram ability like what Neji has in a small arc after the exams

Comment: Thank you. It was kind of killing me to not know, but I didn't really want to spoil myself too much. Do you know what filler episode number that is? I've had [this](http://www.narutohq.com/naruto-shippuden-fillers.php) bookmarked so I can skip filler, but if Hinata is in it (or any other characters I want to learn more about is in it) I'll watch it.

Comment: Actually, is there a way to see which episodes a character is in? I've seen some Wikia's do that before, but I'm really trying to avoid too many spoilers.

Comment: @user3433 unfortunately i don't know the episodes she shows up in or the Arc Naruto joins her team temperoraly, i do know it's after the exams but if i give you a hint about what the Arc is it'll be a major spoiler in on itself

Comment: That's alright. I'm just going to keep on watching the main episodes. Once I've finished them then I can feel easy about going on wikia's/wiki's, and Anime SE. Then I'll be able to see for myself. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @user3433 it might be better to watch all the episodes released first before going to any wiki as they would be updated up to what's been currently released so there will be spoilers

Comment: Even the spoilers? I mean I know that not all of them are terrible, but from what I've read (and what a few friends have told me) they're largely not worth the time.

Comment: OH. You mean I should watch the main series (including Shippuden) before going on wiki's? if that's what you meant then ya that's kind of the plan. I'm not really in that big of a hurry to finish the series, but I've been sort of marathoning it.

Comment: @user3433 if your not in a big hurry then it's probably better to see all the fillers, Hinata's 8 Tri-gram ability is only revealed in a filler and the last filler Arc in the original series i still find that it needs to be seen because of girl Gara helps train, explains her loyalty to him later at the start of Shippuden, there may be more references to the fillers in Shippuden